# Catalan Number for unequal $m$ and $n$

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

The Catalan numbers can be interpreted as the number of paths on an $n\times n$ grid that are never above the diagonal.

I am trying to figure out the generalization where the paths are on an $n\times m$ grid, $m>n$, and the paths do not cross the $(0, 0)--(n, n)$ diagonal.

Any hints?

Edit after 4 years: this is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem

Comment: A [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%20number), representing the number of paths on an $n\times n$ grid, is an expression in $\displaystyle{n+n\choose n}.~$ Your generalized version of Catalan numbers, representing the number of paths on an $m\times n$ grid, must therefore be an expression in $\displaystyle{m+n\choose n}={m+n\choose m}.~$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they have a well established and unambiguous name but Ira Gessel and Guoce Xin  have some related work in the following two papers:

- Ira M. Gessel, [*Super ballot numbers*](http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/papers/superballot.pdf) [PDF], J. Symbolic Computation 14 (1992), 179–194.
- I. M. Gessel and G. Xin, [*A combinatorial interpretation of the numbers* $6(2n)!/n!(n+2)!$](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL8/Gessel/xin.pdf) [PDF], J. Integer Seq. 8 (2005) Article 05.2.3